"UserNotFound" error when connecting to mongodb in docker compose
I’m trying to set up a mongodb instance using docker compose, but I'm running into an authentication issue. here’s my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3.9'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
    environment:
       MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: eagle
       MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
       MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: DB

volumes:
  mongodb: {}

when I try to connect, I get the following error in the logs:
{"t":{"$date":"2024-10-20T00:16:43.975+00:00"},
 "s":"I",
 "c":"ACCESS",
 "id":5286307,
 "ctx":"conn13",
 "msg":"Failed to authenticate",
 "attr":{
   "client":"172.19.0.1:49014",
   "isSpeculative":true,
   "isClusterMember":false,
   "mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256",
   "user":"eagle",
   "db":"DB",
   "error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"eagle\" for db \"DB\"",
   "result":11,
   "metrics":{
     "conversation_duration":{
       "micros":271,
       "summary":{
         "0":{
           "step":1,
           "step_total":2,
           "duration_micros":245
         }
       }
     },
     "extraInfo":{}
   }
 }
}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-10-20T00:16:43.976+00:00"},
 "s":"I",
 "c":"ACCESS",
 "id":6788604,
 "ctx":"conn13",
 "msg":"Auth metrics report",
 "attr":{
   "metric":"acquireUser",
   "micros":0
 }
}

My user "eagle" could not be found for the database "DB." I’ve double-checked the environment variables, and they seem correct.
This connection string should work: mongodb://eagle:123@localhost:27017/DB, but in Datagrid I get this error when I try to connect:
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='eagle', source='DB', password= , mechanismProperties= }

Any insights on how to resolve it would be appreciated!

Have you tried using authSource=admin?

Thanks @ray, I tried RN, didn't work out; same error :(

Delete your data dir folder. If you already started mongodb before without those init params, then the init db stuff won't run because the data folder already exist. It will only be executed the first time, when no data dir exists.

MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE specifies the context for the init scripts, it has nothing to do with the root user.
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME is created in admin database.
As @ray alluded, you have to specify auth database in the command line options. mongosh syntax is --authenticationDatabase=admin so the whole command would be
mongosh -u eagle -p 123 --authenticationDatabase=admin mongodb://localhost:27017/DB

or you can rely on defaults:
mongosh -u eagle -p 123

The last command will log you into test database, so you will need to use DB to switch to DB database.
